# Page caught in a loop when CanvasAuthorizer.Permissions has more than one permission

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have a web project (not mvc) and I am trying to learn about facebook integration (I am a facebook dev noob). In my page I have some simple html and an asp.net button. I added a hidden field for signed_request (for the buttons postback) and that seems ok too. The problem comes in when I try to add multiple permissions in my page_load. If I only check for user_about_me permissions the page seems to work correctly. If I add the publish_stream permission, then the page constantly loops and just loads over and over (getting redirected each time). Here is my page_load code when it loops, to make it not loop I just remove the comma and second permission. Weird thing is EITHER permission works on its own:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer();

  auth.Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me,publish_stream" };
  if (auth.Authorize())
  {
    var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
    dynamic me = fb.Get("me");

    lblAuth.Text = string.Format("User {0} has given permission for this app.", me.name);

  }
  else
  {
    lblAuth.Text = "You have not given permission to this application";
  }
}
```

My aspx looks like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAuth" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<% if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["signed_request"])) { %>

<input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="<%= Request.Params["signed_request"] %>" />

<% } %>
<asp:Button ID="btnPlaceOrder" runat="server" Text="Place Order" 
        onclick="btnPlaceOrder_Click" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblOrderPlaced" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Thanks for any help!!
-Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
auth.Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me,publish_stream" };
```

to

```
 auth.Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "publish_stream" };
```

Comment: oh man, did I really do that?? Its an array -- DUH! Sorry about that. I can't believe I did that. Thanks! I promise not to post non-sdk things again!